Finding a fit function with specific properties
I am looking for a function f(x) for x>0 to fit to monte carlo simulation results. Here is an example of a simulated family of curves that I wish to fit:
simulation results
From the physical process being simulated, I know how the function should behave in the limits x=0 and x=infinity:

$\lim\limits_{x\to 0+} f(x) = x$
$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} f(x) = c$

Furthermore, it should have these properties:

$f'(x) > 0$        (monotonically increasing)
$f''(x) < 0$       (concave)
$f(x)$ must have a parameter $a$ controlling the "smoothness" of the transition between the two limiting behaviors (property 1 and 2).

In the limit of the smoothing parameter, f(x) should become piecewise linear:
$$
f(x) = x \quad x<c
$$
$$
f(x) = c \quad x>c
$$
A function that satisfies conditions 1-4 is:
$$
f(x) = x(1-e^{-c/x})
$$
However, I cannot come up with a modification that allows adjusting the smoothness of the curve without violating one of the other conditions.
Another function is:
$$
g\left(x\right)=c+\frac{1}{2}\left(x-\left(x^{2}+a\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\right)
$$
$$
f\left(x\right)=g\left(x+\left(\frac{a}{4c}-c\right)\right)
$$
Parameter $c$ controls the asymptote on the right, while parameter $a$ controls the "smoothness". This function does not properly satisfy condition 1, although it does approach the intended behavior at negative infinity:  $\lim_{x\to -\infty} f(x) = x$.
For my purposes this works "good enough", but I wonder if there isn't a better solution.
Here are some Desmos plots of the functions listed above:
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/kdc5bpu3uo
